# how to select query for product list in orders table sql

Tags: sql, select, product, orders

my tables:

```
orders:
id | date | customerid

orderDetail:
orderId | Quantity | productId
```

and customer,product table.

output:

list of products exists in orderDetail;

```
Example output:
productname | customername | orderid | Quantity
p1          |  c3          |  4      | 5000
p2          |  c2          |  1      | 1010
p3          |  c5          |  12     | 200
```

what is query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your customer and product tables, but assuming they follow similar naming conventions to the other tables

```
SELECT p.productname, c.customername, od.orderid, od.quantity
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN customers c ON o.customerid = c.id
INNER JOIN orderdetail od ON o.id = od.orderid
INNER JOIN products p ON odproductid = p.id
```

Comment: No problem,  delete all the comments to avoid confusion for future readers

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your column names im putting placeholders inside `< >`

```
SELECT
 p.productname,
 c.customername,
 od.orderid,
 od.quantity
FROM
 orderdetail od
 INNER JOIN order o ON od.orderid = o.id
 INNER JOIN customer c ON c.<customer_id_here> = o.customerid
 INNER JOIN product p ON od.productid = p.<product_id_here>
```